# MySQL Multiple Duplicate Rows - Return Only One

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I imported my iTunes Library into a table via a script.  The script doesn't catch any duplicate song title and artists.  Therefore, I have many duplicate songs.

```
trackid    song    artist   tracknum
4628       Title1  StackO      2
6846       YMCA    (blank)     11
9043       YMCA    (blank)     11
9381       YMCA    (blank)     11
9382       Title2  StackO      3
```

How would I write my SQL statement to return only the FIRST "trackid" of YMCA (4628) row when the song, artist and tracknum are all the same?  It should look like this....

```
trackid    song    artist   tracknum
4628       Title1  StackO      2
6846       YMCA    (blank)     11
9382       Title2  StackO      3
```

Here is my SQL as it stands right now...

`"SELECT DISTINCT * FROM wp_tracks WHERE title LIKE '%" . $song . "%' AND artist LIKE '%" . $artist . "%'`

This has been baffling me for awhile now.

Thank you.

Comment: @u_mulder - I also need a trackid to be returned.  That would just return it once, but as I stated in my question, I need the first result returned, that way I have the song, artist and trackid

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by `FIRST` because that implies ordering and you haven't explicitly said what order you want... so `FIRST` and `LAST` don't actually make any sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT song, artist, tracknum, MIN(trackid) AS first_track_id
FROM wp_tracks
GROUP BY song, artist, tracknum
```

Add a WHERE clause to choose which tracks you want listed.

Comment: +1 Perhaps a `ORDER BY trackid ASC` as well to cover 'return only the FIRST "trackid" of YMCA (4628)'

Comment: @AlexP Actually, the OP hasn't clarified whether FIRST means MIN in this context

Comment: @AlexP The fact that the data happens to match a MIN doesn't need to mean it is really expecting a MIN. IMO, it is most likely that the OP is just wanting to remove duplicates no matter the `trackid` that's why he mentions `the first`. So it is most likely that the aggregate function isn't even necessary and just leave the `trackid` alone in the select to improve query efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention what column you want to be DISTINCT, in your case `song`

```
SELECT DISTINCT song FROM wp_tracks
WHERE title LIKE '%" . $song . "%' AND artist LIKE '%" . $artist . "%
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It is missing columns.